# How do I avoid "sleeping" processes in MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

Currently I'm experiencing alot of issues with Server Processes (Seen from sp_who2) that is "sleeping" instead of just, finishing (being removed), when I connection to my MSSQL Database, calls a Stored Procedure, get some data and then closing the connection.

What's the best way in C#/.NET to connect to a MSSQL database, call a Stored Procedure, retrieve data from the Stored Procedure (Data Reader) and then close the connection?

Is there a way to close/dispose so that the "sleeping" processes gets killed?

Does it have something to do with me creating new SqlConnections, opening them and closing them all the time?

My flow is as follows:

A request occur:

1. I create a new SqlConnection Instance that connects to my MSSQL Database.
2. I call a Stored Procedure, retrieve the data and presents it to the user.
3. I close the Connection with `.Close();`
4. I repeat all these steps for each request. Requests happen once every 5-10 seconds. (Sometimes slower, sometimes faster)

I'm sorry If this question is missing some details, but I hope this is enough to get a some what helpful answer.

Thanks!

Comment: This is expected behavior -- connections are pooled and a number of them are kept available at all times to minimize the overhead of setting up physical connections. Closing a connection doesn't really close it, it just makes it available to the pool again. What are the "problems" you're experiencing? Is the number of active sessions actually increasing or do you just *think* there's something wrong because these sessions are present at all? Your general use is correct, but rather than explicitly calling `.Close()`, prefer `using`: this is safe even in the face of exceptions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would post it as an answer, adding a link to the msdn doc on the subject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My assumption of something is wrong, is that when theres alot of "sleeping" processes, the database gets slower and slower, and when I tried to clear these "sleeping" processes, the database became faster. Is that just a coincedence?

Comment: Pooled connections will be physically closed after a couple of minutes of non-use. Wrap connections and commands in a `using` block so they are automatically closed and disposed.

Comment: Is the application using integrated security to connect to the database? check the 'Pool fragmentation' sectino on the above link.

Comment: @bradbury9 It is not. I'm connecting to it through it's external IP (In this case It's an endpoint from Amazon RDS)

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen: hard to tell without actually seeing the server and the application. Sleeping processes take up memory, but they otherwise take up almost no resources at all. However, if you have a fast resource leak in your application (so the number of connections grows without limit) then that *will* eventually bring any server to its knees. Monitor `select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections` for a bit. That said, IIRC, if you have only *one* instance of the application, it should eventually hit the connection pool limit long before the server is even slightly bothered.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SET XACT_ABORT ON or add some client rollback code

When a client timeout event occurs (.net CommandTimeout for example), the client sends an "ABORT" to SQL Server. SQL Server then simply abandons the query processing. No transaction is rolled back, no locks are released.

Now, the connection is returned to the connection pool, so it isn't closed on SQL Server. If this ever happens (via KILL or client reboot etc) then the transactions+locks will be cleared. Note that sp_reset_connection won't or doesn't clear them, even though it is advertised to do so

This detritus from the abort will block other processes.

The way to make SQL Server clear transactions+locks on client timeout (strictly, ABORT events) is to use SET XACT_ABORT ON.

You can verify this be opening 2 query windows in SSMS:

**Window 1:**

In menu Query..Query Options set a timeout of 5 seconds then run this

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE sometable WITH (TABLOCKX) SET foo = foo WHERE 1 = 0;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' -- just has to be longer then timeout
```

**Window 2, this will wait forever (or hit your timeout)**

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
```